# Java SOOT framework: Does SOOT support anonymous Threads?

Tags: soot

Has anyone used SOOT framework to work with anonymous Threads? I have tried but soot does not seem to recognize the function definitions inside anonymous Threads.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, anonymous or not should not make any difference.